# Parse out specific parameter from python script

Tags: linux, bash, script, python

I have a chage output that I formatted myself called accounts. It basically has the name of the user listed as a section and then the information below it (which are the parameters). I would like to basically parse out any accounts that have Account expires = never and give me the section name to a new file. Here is what the file 'accounts looks like:

```
[user1]
Last_password_change = password_must_be_changed
Password_expires = never
Password_inactive = never
Account_expires = never
Minimum_number_of_days_between_password_change = 7
Maximum_number_of_days_between_password_change = 90
Number_of_days_of_warning_before_password_expires = 14

[user2]
Last_password_change = password_must_be_changed
Password_expires = never
Password_inactive = never
Account_expires = never
Minimum_number_of_days_between_password_change = 7
Maximum_number_of_days_between_password_change = 90
Number_of_days_of_warning_before_password_expires = 14
```

Here is what I have so far but can't seem to get it exactly the way I'd like it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from ConfigParser import RawConfigParser
import re
import sys

# Read configuration from ~/accounts
_cfg = RawConfigParser()
_cfg.read('accounts')
cfg = dict()
for sect in _cfg.sections():
        cfg[sect] = dict()
        for (name, value) in _cfg.items(sect):
                cfg[sect][name] = value

                if cfg[sect]['Account_expires'] == "never":

                        f = open('access','w')
                        f.write('still has access')
                        f.close()
```

I realize I am only putting 'still has access' in the new file called 'access' but I would really like to output the username there. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `grep -B4 'Account_expires = never' accounts.txt | grep '\['`

Comment: That does work great and appreciate it. Any chance on a python way to do it as well?

Comment: Sorry, I know BASIC, Logo (programming language), C, C++, Assembler on Intel 8085, Perl, awk, sed, Regex, Cobol and bash but no python.

Comment: OK the reason I was looking for a python way is because I realize that I also need to also grep for "Password_inactive = never". So if either of these are never, I would like the user. The problem with using grep -B4 is that if only the Password inactive is set to never, I won't be able to grep out the user. Any work arounds?

Comment: My mistake. I need to grep for both of them since either one would signify a locked account. But both being never would mean they are still accessible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I noticed actually worked. I change len(never) == 1 to len(never) == 2. It seems to work and I assume it is because it is looking for an exact length of 2 matches of never for those two options (the account expires and password inactive fields). Am I right?

```
users = []
for sect in _cfg.sections():
    never = []
    for (name, value) in _cfg.items(sect):
        print("# %s: %s = %s" % (sect, name, value))
        # Notice that the names are normalized to all lowercase
        if name in ['account_expires', 'password_inactive'] and value=="never":
            never.append(name)
    # Slightly ugly, check for exactly one value in "never"
    if len(never) == 2:
        users.append(sect)
for user in users:
    print("User %s still has access" % user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have code which needlessly copies stuff over to a different array.  This is trimmed down to a simple loop over the results from `_cfg`.  I am not writing `access` but hint at how to collect all information, then write it all out finally at the end, after the main loop.  (If you have a lot of data, writing as you read starts to make sense again, but for a simple, quick job, I would collect, then write.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from ConfigParser import RawConfigParser


# Read configuration from ~/accounts
_cfg = RawConfigParser()
_cfg.read('accounts')

users = []
for sect in _cfg.sections():
    for (name, value) in _cfg.items(sect):
        # Notice that the names are normalized to all lowercase
        if name in ['account_expires', 'password_inactive'] and value=="never":
            users.append(sect)
            break  # done with this user, break out of inner loop
for user in users:
    print("User %s still has access" % user)
```

You were never using `re` or `sys` in the first place, and there was some other dead code in your script as well.

Comment: I think there is an error in your script. I intentionally modified the value from never to another value and the script still returned that the user has access. Can you include the full script with the modules to be loaded as well?

Comment: Works for me here.  Added the (obvious) missing parts, though.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your last comment to the question, though.  I interpreted "I need to grep for both of them since either one would signify a locked account. But both being never would mean they are still accessible" to mean that it's a special case if they are both "Never".  If you (still) simply need to check if at least one of them is "Never", the script can be simplifed -- just use a simple flag and set it to `True` instead of appending to `never` (just replace the array with a boolean).

Comment: I made this simplification.  Check the earlier version from the edit history of this answer if you don't want this.